# How to declare an accessor to a member?

Tags: c++, getter

In some of the classes accessors are declared like `getName1` and in others like `getName2`. From the usage perspective, it looks identical. Are there any performance benefit of one over the other in a decent compiler? Are there any cases where I should use only one of the two?

```
class MyClass
{
  public:
    MyClass(const string& name_):_name(name_)
  {
  }
    string getName1() const
    {
      return _name;
    }
    const string& getName2() const
    {
      return _name;
    }
  private:
    string _name;
};

int main()
{
  MyClass c("Bala");
  string s1 = c.getName1();
  const string& s2 = c.getName1();
  string s3 = c.getName2();
  const string& s4 = c.getName2();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's not quite identical for the user. If `c._name` changes, then `s4` will give the new value, while the others will retain the old value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Returning by reference is *potentially* faster, because no copy needs to be made (although in many circumstances the [*return-value optimization*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization) applies.

However, it also increases coupling.  Consider what happens if you want to change the internal implementation of your class so that you store the name in a different way (i.e. no longer in a `string`).  There will no longer be something to return by reference, so you will also need to change your public interface, which means client code will need to be recompiled.

Comment: In which case of the above four it is potentially faster? `const string& s2 = c.getName1();` Does this create any copies?

Comment: @balki: `const string& s2 = c.getName1();` almost certainly does need to create a copy. First, `s2`'s referand must have a different address from `c._name`. Second, if `c._name` is modified by another bit of code, then the string referred to by `s2` must not reflect that change. So unless the compiler can prove to itself that no such change occurs, and that you don't do anything else that relies on the two being at different addresses, then it can't avoid a copy. Proving such things is hard, I don't think compilers really try much.

Comment: @Steve Got this. But how does it increase coupling? If I choose to change the internal implementation, how does it affect if I return copy or reference?

Comment: If you change the internal implementation, there may no longer be a bit of data internally that can be returned by reference. For a trivial example, suppose we replace `_name` with `_firstname` and `_lastname`; now the result of `getName` needs to be computed (by concatenating the strings), and thus needs to be returned by value anyway. If you'd returned by value from the start, you'd avoid the need to recompile.

Answer (score 1):

```
string getName1() const
{
    return _name;
}
```

The compiler can seriously do RVO(return value optimization) in this case.

[This article from Dave Abrahams may help.](http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/)

Comment: I am neither returning a temporary nor a local stack variable, How can compiler optimize return value in this case `string s1 = c.getName1();` ? Atleast one copy has to be made.

Comment: @balki: obviously one copy has to be made for `string s1 = c.getName1();`, RVO just means that it's only 1, not 2. Likewise, 1 copy is made for `string s1 = c.getName2();`.

Comment: The case where they differ is `std::cout << c.getName()` where if you return by value a copy **must** be done (unless the code is inlined, the compiler is very smart and the planets align, i.e. the compiler can prove that the member is unaliased). If you return a reference, then no copies will be performed. RVO, the article by Abrahams and a couple more I [wrote](http://definedbehavior.blogspot.com/2011/08/value-semantics-nrvo.html) deal with functions that **create** objects (for the return case), but an accessor need not create anything.