# How to return the value of a private member string in a class

Tags: c++, getter

I want to get the value of a private string `name` in `sampleclass`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class sampleclass {
public:
    int getname(){ //this is my attempted getter
    string x = name;
    }
private:
    string name= "lance"; //this is the private I want returned by value

};

int main(){    
    sampleclass object;
    cout << object.getname();
}
```

Comment: If it's getting a name, why is it returning (although it isn't even returning anything) an `int`?

Comment: `string getname() { return name; }`

Comment: @MatthewLundberg, It should in C++11.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to declare an accessor to a member?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9616689/how-to-declare-an-accessor-to-a-member)

Comment: @chris Good point; I keep forgetting about that feature.

Comment: alright so guys I cant declare a string that are on private?

Comment: @MatthewLundberg You are referring to the non-static data member initializers I presume? ( I'm not sure I'll EVER get used to seeing that lol )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to return a string in your `getname()` function, since your `name` variable is a string

```
string getname() {
    return name;
}
```

By doing so, you get a new instance of `std::string` as an `rvalue` result, which is then outputted to the screen in your main function.

As another thought, not related to your problem though: there is no problem in using a namespace globally for small programs like this one, but you should [try to not get used to it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) because it can lead to name conflicts within different namespaces in bigger projects.

Comment: I thought it's this->name

Comment: @Nighthawk441 `this->` is implied (unless there is a need for scope resolution).

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class sampleclass{
public:
    sampleclass() : name("lance") { }
    string getname(){ // return a string (not an int)
       return name;
    }
private:
    string name;

};
int main(){

    sampleclass object;
    cout << object.getname();

}
```

`g++ test.cpp && ./a.out 
lance`

Comment: `name` was already correctly initialized (it's semantically equivalent to this).

Comment: Is that valid C++ code? Haven't ever seen that in real world code.

Comment: It's valid C++11 code, which I can only assume the OP is using if writing code like that.

Comment: Ok, learned something new then, looks weird though. Anyway, I don't think he is writing C++11, since this question isn't tagged C++11.

Comment: alright so I couldn't declare a string that are on private?

Comment: As far as I know, the C++ tag implies C++11 now, not to say that everyone uses it as such.

Comment: @chris, that's an unusually bold assumption in this case when OP is continuing to struggle to understand matching of return types :-) but quite interesting

Comment: @UpAndAdam, I do realize that, although the OP didn't mention any errors from it. I doubt that syntax would come from the OP being a C# or Java programmer either for your mentioned reason.

Comment: @user3490590: It seems to be correct as long you are writing C++11 code. If you are writing C++03/C++98 code, then you must/should initialize them the way I did.

Comment: @chris: Visual C++ defaults to C++11 afaik.

Comment: @thomas ok sir, thanks! sorry im a newbie.

Comment: @Thomas, That's correct, but only the most recent version(s) support this feature.

Comment: @chris likewise, hence it was a very worthwhile and interesting read for me, and it also kept the focus on the 'more problematic' part of  what op had done wrong.  (I figured it was OP just trying intersting things out, I've seen people try writing that before C++0X and C++11X even started when I was a TA during college)